# Oracle Apex 5.1.2 update table depending if the checkbox is checked or unchecked

Tags: oracle, checkbox

im new to oracle apex and what im trying to do is pass a value depending on the state of the checkbox, if it is 'checked' then is 1 if it is 'unchecked' is 0
right now im using this code

```
BEGIN
  FOR i in 1..APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01.COUNT LOOP
  UPDATE XXFE4_SAT_CATALOGOS_CFDI_33
  SET activo = 1
  WHERE ID_CATALOGO = APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01(i);
  END LOOP;
  COMMIT;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Dynamic Action on the Item (checkbox)
WHEN => Item => Change
ACTION => Execute PL/SQL Code
and Enter your code